# Import pmml file created in R

Tags: r, sas, pmml

I want to import in SAS an XGBoost classification model with pmml file created in R.
It's created with pmml package `pmml_2.3.1` in `R version 3.6.2`.
The pmml file version is `PMML version="4.4"`, but I manually change it to `PMML version="4.2"`

when I import it in SAS with this command:

```
PROC PSCORE PMML FILE = "PATH.pmml"
DS FILE = "PATH.sas";
run;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Given PMML File is not well formed or correct, error near line
> number: 598897.

This is on the line 598897 in the pmml file:

```
<RegressionModel functionName="classification" normalizationMethod="softmax" modelName="CollectingModel">
```

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like you may not be the only one. I would contact SAS tech support on this issue or at least post in communities.sas.com for a more direct SAS response. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Science/Light-GBM-Python-Integration-node-gives-quot-ERROR-Given-PMML/m-p/831847

Answer (score 1):

You cant import, based on SAS documentation:

PROC PSCORE currently supports the use of PMML 4.2. Earlier versions of PMML are not supported for use with PROC PSCORE

So, if you are just changing the pmml version manually. 4.4 to 4.2 it will not help

Answer (score 0):

The legacy `pmml` package is known to generate terribly inefficient PMML markup. Does the situation improve if you re-export your XGBoost model using the [`r2pmml`](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) package?

Comment: With r2pmml I get: "ERROR: Improper Attribute in element MiningModel".
This is the node - <MiningModel functionName="classification" algorithmName="XGBoost (GBTree)" x-mathContext="float">
The same pmml file is imported in python without issues.

Comment: If you remove the `x-mathContext` vendor extension element, does it load then?

Comment: Like this? : `<MiningModel functionName="classification" algorithmName="XGBoost (GBTree)">`
Now I have error in line 40, which is : `<MiningModel functionName="regression" x-mathContext="float">`
If I delete `x-mathContent` the same error appears.